# Join to pull matches and non match based on IN statement

Tags: sql

I am having some trouble joining two tables which I want to return match and non-matches based on an IN clause.

```
SELECT * FROM detail p
LEFT OUTER JOIN inventory e on p.style = e.style
WHERE det_id in ('123','456','789','101') and p.warehouse = e.warehouse
and p.partner = e.partner
```

I understand the where clause may be removing the null values however I am not getting the results I am expecting when it is removed.

The inventory table will sometimes hold a match to the detail table however I will always want to return any record in detail where det_id is given regardless of a match being found. I am finding my matches to null are being left out of the return.

Comment: Edit your question and qualify all the column names (so we know what table they come from) and provide a database tag.

Comment: which database you use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you want something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM detail p LEFT OUTER JOIN
     inventory e 
     ON p.style = e.style AND p.warehouse = e.warehouse AND
        p.partner = e.partner AND
WHERE d.det_id in (123, 456, 789, 101) ;
```

Any condition on the *second* table needs to be in the `ON` clause for the `LEFT JOIN` to work.  A condition *only* on the first table should be in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the `left outer join` and replace it with a `left join`.

```
SELECT *
FROM detail p 
LEFT JOIN inventory e 
ON p.partner = e.partner
AND p.warehouse = e.warehouse 
AND p.style = e.style
WHERE p.det_id in (123, 456, 789, 101)
```

You will always see results if those `det_id` exists on `detail` table.